# Why am I getting no reverse match error in django 3.2?

Tags: python, django

I am making a simple todo list application but while adding a delete button, I am receiving the error.
I tried many things searching on internet but couldn't solve the issue, probably because i am new to django.So, your help will be very important.

urls.py(of app):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.home,name='home'),
url('delete/<str:id>', views.delete_data,name='deldata'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render,redirect
from todo.models import value
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


# Create your views here.
from .forms import TitleForm
from django.urls import reverse




def home(request):
   values=value.objects.all()    
   form=TitleForm
   if request.method=='POST':
      form=TitleForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
  else:
      form=TitleForm()
  return render(request,'home.html',{'values':values,'form':form})



 #delete

 def delete_data(request, id ):

    ggwp=value.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method=="POST":
       ggwp=value.objects.get(id=id)
       ggwp.delete()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('deldata', kwargs={'id':id}))
    context={'ggwp':ggwp}
    return render(request,'/',context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class value(models.Model):
   task=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   complete=models.BooleanField(default=False)
   created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.task
```

home.html(One and only html page):

```
<h3>TO DO LIST</h3>
<form method="POST" action="\">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form.task}} <input type='submit' name='add' value="add" > 
</form>
{% for val in values %}
  {{val}}
  <form action="{% url 'deldata' val.id %}" method="POST" class="in-line">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" >
  </form>



{% endfor %}
```

traceback:

```
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
 django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'deldata' with arguments '(15,)' not 
  found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/<str:id>']
 [05/Oct/2021 22:37:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 127858
```

Its my first question, so sorry if I have made any mistakes while writing the question.

Comment: The `url` (old, replaced by `re_path` currently) function and the `path` function are not the same thing, you use `url` as if it were `path`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse for 'deletedata' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: \['delete/<int:id>/'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915932/reverse-for-deletedata-with-keyword-arguments-pk-1-not-found-1-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) syntax with the [**`url(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.url). You should work with a `path(…)` here:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    # ↓ path, not url
    path('delete/<str:id>/', views.delete_data,name='deldata'),
]
```

Normally paths also end with a slash, altough that is not required, it is common.

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.